# debug IE6 JavaScript within Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, debugging, internet-explorer-6

I'm looking for an Eclipse plugin that will enable me to debug JavaScript running in IE6. Ideally, I'd like to be able to just attach the debugger to a running instance of IE6, but if I have to start IE6 from within Eclipse, I could live with that.

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 2):

I think [Apanta](http://www.aptana.com/) does some [JS IE debugging](http://www.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Installing_the_IE_debugger), but i think you will need the pro version...

best of all it [plugs into Eclpise](http://www.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Plugging_Aptana_into_an_existing_Eclipse_configuration)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do it within Eclipse?

You could do it within IE, I haven't tried this, but it looks useful:
http://www.debugbar.com/?langage=en

I used VS2005 for my IE6 debugging (painful).

Comment: I've tried using the Visual Web Debugger component of VS. Compared to Firebug, it's utter rubbish.

Comment: I found an extension that comes bundled with IE8, that was very useful. I think it was Web Developer, that I was using on IE7.
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1):

I find [CompanionJS](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/CompanionJS/HomePage) to be very effective. Its Javascript console looks very much like Firebug.